# How to access Session state in standard Java class?

Tags: java, session, servlets

I need a mechanism to read session state from a Java class, without having to pass any arguments (including HttpRequest) to the class. The reason is that the class is 1-3 calls away from the servlet and i dont want to pollute the method argument list with an extra arg for every call.
I basically have the same prob of these guys: 
http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5124189

For which apparently Java does not have a solution currently..

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tempting mechanism is to use ThreadLocal storage, but in some App Servers this is dangerous - the App Server may use pools of Threads and a single request may be processed by different threads at different points.

Some App Servers (I know WebSphere does) offer a specific API for this purpose. In WAS it's a UserWorkArea. See [here](http://websphere.sys-con.com/node/48334) for a reference, a little way down the article.

I'm not aware of a portable solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, we are doing this in WAS. And for the same reason I didn't come up with this suggestion. So, I would say +1.

Comment: Found this, http://www.devwebsphere.com/devwebsphere/2005/06/dont_use_thread.html. Quite old though, but I think its worth reading it.

Comment: Thanks, im using Tomcat6 and not sure if it's 1 thread/request... will look into thread local - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do not pass HttpSession to you "standard" Java classes. For better solutions check dependency injection containers like Spring or Guice and read about session scope.

This is normally solved by a combination of a thread local pattern and a servlet filter, but it's normally bad to have "standard" Java classes to access session, request, and so on directly.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be the use of [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). Be careful to clean it at the end of your request.

Comment: how do i know when is the end of the request? do you know if i can use threadlocal safely inside struts interceptors?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is in effect a global variable, and "polluting" the parameter lists in your other classes is a lot cleaner. It gets easier to read and test.

If you want to avoid your code depending on servlet.jar, use the adapter pattern: Make an interface of the operations you need, let your methods accept an argument of that interface, and make a simple wrapper implementation of it that just delegates to the HttpSession.